# Why are second-order tensor invariants different if calculated in dual basis?

Tags: tensors

Disclaimer: I'm an student in engineering, so please forgive me asking this stupid question.

Consider the following tensor coordinates given: The covariant coordinates of the metric tensor $\boldsymbol{g}$ and the contra variant coordinates of a 2-nd order tensor $\boldsymbol{A}$.

$
[g_{ij}]=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\qquad
[A^{ij}]=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, 
$

I know how to compute the covariant and mixed coordinates of $\boldsymbol{A}$: $A_{ij}=g_{ik}g_{jl}A^{kl}$ and $A_{i}^{.j}=g_{ik}A^{kj}$ yielding

$
[A_{ij}]=\begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 & 0 \\
        2 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 12 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
[A_{i}^{.j}]=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, 
$

Now why do the all the invariants $tr(\boldsymbol{A})$, $tr(\boldsymbol{A}^2)$, $tr(\boldsymbol{A}^3)$, $\frac{1}{2}(tr(\boldsymbol{A})^2-tr(\boldsymbol{A}^2))$ and $det(\boldsymbol{A})$ change if I compute them from either $[A_{ij}]$,$[A^{ij}]$ or$[A_{i}^{.j}]$?

I thought the nice property of them was just that they do **not** change regardless of the basis I write the tensor in!

Comment: As far as I know, $[A_{ij}], [A^{ij}]$, and $[A_i^j]$ are *different* tensors. They are all isomorphically related by formulas involving $g$ which allows you to calculate, say $[A_{ij}](\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l})$ knowing $[A_i^j](\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\otimes dx^l)$, or something like that. But as mathematical objects they are different tensors. This shouldn't be confused with writing the same tensor in a different basis - that's not what's happening here.

Comment: Ok, so I my lecture on tensor algebra, a basis and its associated dual basis are just two different bases of **the same** euclidian vector space related by $g_i\cdot g^j=\delta_i^j$. So from that perspective there is no difference between choosing a different basis or going to the dual basis. I guess I am then hitting the boundary of this simplified approach here...?

Comment: They aren't bases of the same Euclidean vector space! One is the dual of the other! We have the musical isomorphisms between them, but I don't remember if these should preserve traces. A priori I don't see why, but I must stop here because I forgot how the trace of a tensor is defined and I might misinform you. All I do know for sure is that each of those is a different tensor on a different space.

Comment: This is not very precise. One does however get away with this mathematically doubtful perception of dual bases spanning the same space by enforcing a Ricci summation convention so that calculating the traces is only possible by summation over one upper and one lower index. This renders the traces invariant in this context.